# Sessionstorage - Store everything

Tags: html, local-storage, session-storage

I've read a lot about the new Sessionstorage possibility but nowhere have I heard about the idea to save everything like images (base64), html, css a.s.o. for the single session. Is there a reason not to do this? If a user goes back to a page everything will load within milliseconds. I can see why not to use Localstorage but as its a single session it should not be harmful and only give a little boost to speed when the users are surfing a big site.

Comment: Browsers have had the ability to cache html, css, js, and images since forever. Using the proper cache-control headers and versioning resources does what you seem to be asking about - so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

SessionStorage should be used for storing session data. Images aren't session data.
For the storing of images, styles, scripts etc. use HTTP caching.

**What if you change your stylesheets or images?** The sessionStorage wouldn't know they were changed. Visitors are stuck with old data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save Image use Manifest not SessionStorage.
In Manifest file you can cache what you want this may be a solution for you.

You  may be interested by reading this article

http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: Thanks! I've read up a lot in html5 as I'm possessed with speed of my apps, but I'll do some more reading :)